# How to Change the Width of the Column in dynamical approach

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a default width value for a column in my table. I want the user to be able to change the width of the column by using his cursor and dragging the header (Like how you do in MS Excel).

I use jQuery and Bootstrap.
How do I do it?

Code:

```css
table{
    border: 1px solid black;
}

th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<table>
   <tr>
      <th>header 1</th>
      <th>header 2</th>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>data </td>
      <td>data 2</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>data asdfassdfasdf</td>
      <td>data 2</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>data asdfasdfasdfasdfasdf</td>
      <td>data 2 sdf sdfsdf</td>
   </tr>    
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You mean it should be resizable?

if it is then i can suggest you to use jquery UI since you use already jquery.

https://jqueryui.com/resizable/

hope it will help :D

Answer (score 0):

[JSFIDDLE DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/cfo07mk5/1/)
I'm in a hurry, so I haven't fully tested it, so this could be a start.
The idea is to check if you are clickking inside a cell and retrieve the element and the pointer position, then once you relase the button you calculate the differente position of the pointer and add (it can be positive or negative) this difference at the cell width(if negative set width to 1px).
The main missing logic is to check the cell border, because it's a little bit difficult, the better approach should be to calculate the difference between the pointer position and the border, then add it to `newW` calc

```
var iniCellW,
iniPointerPos,
selectedCell,
isCell = false;

$('tr > td').on('mousedown', function (e) {
    //option a: check if the border is cliccked
    isCell = true;
    selectedCell = $(this);
    iniPointerPos = e.pageX.toFixed(0);
});


$(document).on('mouseup', function (e) {
    if (isCell) {
        isCell = false;
        var widthChange = e.pageX.toFixed(0) - iniPointerPos,
            cellW = parseInt(selectedCell.css('width').replace('px','')),
            newW = cellW + widthChange, //option b:add the difference border logic
            setW = (newW > 0) ? newW+'px' : 1+'px';
        selectedCell.css('width', setW);
    }
});
```

Obviously a well tested plugin is better, but if you want to do it by yourself maybe could be a point to start

**EDIT**
This is semi-working one with some more options, it has got some problems(In JSFidlle doesn't work, I think it is due the fact the script retrieve the left magin, you should it at some point related t a parent level)

```
var iniCellW,
    iniAbsPointerPos,
    iniRelPointerPos=0,
    selectedCell,
    isCell = false,
    resizeOnPointerMove = true,
    onlyBorderClick=true,
    clickMaxError=10;

$('tr > td, tr > th').on('mousedown', function (e) {

    selectedCell = $(this),
    iniAbsPointerPos = e.pageX.toFixed(0),
    iniCellW = parseInt($(this).css('width').replace('px',''));

    var diffBorder=0,
        el = this;

    while(el && !isNaN(el.offsetLeft)){
        diffBorder += el.offsetLeft - ((el.srollLeft)?el.srollLeft:0) ;
        el=el.offsetParent;
    }

    while(diffBorder<iniAbsPointerPos){
        diffBorder+=iniCellW;
    };

    iniRelPointerPos = diffBorder - iniAbsPointerPos;

    if(onlyBorderClick && Math.abs(iniRelPointerPos) < clickMaxError)
        isCell = true;
    else if(!onlyBorderClick)
        isCell = true;

});

$(document).on('mouseup', function (e) {
    if (isCell) {
        isCell = false;
        var widthChange = e.pageX.toFixed(0) - iniAbsPointerPos,
            newW = iniCellW + widthChange - ((resizeOnPointerMove && widthChange!=0)? iniRelPointerPos:0),
            setW = (newW > 0) ? newW+'px' : 1+'px';
        selectedCell.css('width', setW);
    }
});
```